# What benefits OS virtualization offer as opposed server virtualization?

Tags: docker, virtualization

I am going through various virtualization concepts, and am trying to understand their benefits.

Based on what I have read, Amazon EC2 is an example of server/hardware virtualization, and it helps us achieve high utlization of hardware. In the absence of hypervisor, we would have low utlization rate of hardware. Also, server proliferation.

Docker/Containers on the other hand is an example of OS virtualization. Here we can have multiple OS running on a single host OS; However that is possible with server virtualization as well. So, what benefit do we get with Docker/OS virtualization?

Comment: [What research did you do before posting this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)